# How get parametrs from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Full code:

```
$.post('test.php', {
id: id
},function (data) {
console.log(data);
var Server = data.response.server;
var Photo = data.response.photo;

console.log(Server);
console.log(Photo);

});
```

in `data` i get json:

```
{
"server":9458,
"photo":
 "[{\"photo\":\"0d6a293fad:x\",\"sizes\":  
    [[\"s\",\"9458927\",\"1cb7\",\"PX_xDNKIyYY\",75,64],
    [\"m\",\"9458927\",\"1cb8\",\"GvDZr0Mg5zs\",130,111], 
    [\"x\",\"9458927\",\"1cb9\",\"sRb1abTcecY\",420,360], 
    [\"o\",\"9458927\",\"1cba\",\"J0WLr9heJ64\",130,111], 
    [\"p\",\"9458927\",\"1cbb\",\"yb3kCdI-Mlw\",200,171], 
    [\"q\",\"9458927\",\"1cbc\",\"XiS0fMy-QqI\",320,274],
    [\"r\",\"9458927\",\"1cbd\",\"pU4VFIPRU0k\",420,360]], 
    \"kid\":\"7bf1820e725a4a9baea4db56472d76b4\"}]", 
"hash":"f030356e0d096078dfe11b706289b80a"
}
```

I would like get parametrs `server` and `photo[photo]`

for this i use:

```
var Server = data.server;
var Photo = data.photo;

console.log(Server);
console.log(Photo);
```

but in concole i get `undefined`

Than i use code:

```
var Server = data.response.server;
var Photo = data.response.photo;

console.log(Server);
console.log(Photo);
```

But now in console i see:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'server' of undefined`

Why i get errors and how get parametrs?

P.S.: All code php and jquery find [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mKcB388nGG9q0wTXWLm4?p=info)

Comment: How are you retrieving the json? What is the context for your code?

Comment: can you console data `console.log(data)` and see whats in there?

Comment: If that JSON has already been parsed, `data.server` and `data.photo` should work just fine. Please include a **full** example which demonstrates the problem. I suspect there's some ajax involved - let's see [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: @Brandon json i get when send $post in jquery. next: `function(data){var Server = data.response.server;
var Photo = data.response.photo;});`

Comment: Please try this...  `var json_text = JSON.stringify(data.response, null, 4); obj = JSON.parse(json_text); alert(obj.server)`

Comment: That is a really weird stringification.

Comment: @MattBall i add full code in up question - see please

Comment: I really don't understand why you treat "photo" as a string...

Comment: What did you get on `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @EugineJoseph `Error Unexpected token u ` on line `obj = JSON.parse(json_text);`

Comment: @SilverBlade console.log(data) show:

`{"server":9458,"photo":"[{\"photo\":\"f2b6077c61:x\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"9458927\",\"1cc5\",\"kzg-6n6WThs\",75,64],[\"m\",\"9458927\",\"1cc6\",\"aIO5fIHmGKw\",130,111],[\"x\",\"9458927\",\"1cc7\",\"SRvtpsQx1WE\",420,360],[\"o\",\"9458927\",\"1cc8\",\"U_LVqVEGypU\",130,111],[\"p\",\"9458927\",\"1cc9\",\"QVcqLJawXUs\",200,171],[\"q\",\"9458927\",\"1cca\",\"stH1shsVUek\",320,274],[\"r\",\"9458927\",\"1ccb\",\"Wv5gDrS1NYI\",420,360]],\"kid\":\"7bf1820e725a4a9baea4db56472d76b4\"}]","hash":"8d95f93e27ee969eb5ab18bc98d99b17"}`

Comment: please add your code in http://plnkr.co/

Comment: @EugineJoseph http://plnkr.co/edit/mKcB388nGG9q0wTXWLm4

Comment: Please update test.php too.

Comment: @EugineJoseph see again please http://plnkr.co/edit/mKcB388nGG9q0wTXWLm4?p=info in test.php i show code which give data for $.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set proper data type `json`, the default one is `string`.

And your data is directly under `data` variable!

```
$.post('test.php', {
    id: id
},function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var Server = data.server;
    var Photo = data.photo;

    console.log(Server);
    console.log(Photo);

}, 'json');
```

Another solution is setting proper header in you PHP response:

```
Content-Type    text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
```

then jQuery  `Intelligent Guess`, will set proper data type itself.

Comment: Big thanks- - i dont know it =) But tell me please - in `console.log(data.photo);` i get `[{"photo":"06d7fb3797:x","sizes":[["s","9458927","1cef","Y-uMZImBZNM",75,64],["m","9458927","1cf0","aNBe-6ndoaI",130,111],["x","9458927","1cf1","vNg-mT8Jqyw",420,360],["o","9458927","1cf2","N7mZ8WRVUSE",130,111],["p","9458927","1cf3","8IkfS7lIrQ4",200,171],["q","9458927","1cf4","9510OAyFNVw",320,274],["r","9458927","1cf5","XLmaOe2sV_0",420,360]],"kid":"7bf1820e725a4a9baea4db56472d76b4"}] `

**How get photo in `data.photo`?? i do data.photo.photo but i  get `undefined ` in console... How get it ?**

Comment: `data.photo` is array so to get first photo in that array do `data.photo[0].photo`. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct one;)

Comment: i use `var Photo = data.photo[0].photo;` but in console i again see `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method, exposed by jQuery. This enables you to map the properties to a type, of sorts, such as:

```
var results = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    alert(results[i].name + ":" + results[i].date);
}
```

You may need to tweak the inputs and exact use of the outputs in accordance with your data and requirements.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` on line `for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {`

Comment: @TeopLome that's not a problem of this answer. What precedes the place you put this code?

Comment: @TeopLome: This code work correctly, you need to check where you put that code, because the error was SyntaxError means there are some syntax was missed.

Comment: @TeopLome are you trying to put code inside an object (or array) literal?

Comment: @IshanJain when i close `/* */` code `for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       console.log(results[i].name + ":" + results[i].date);
       alert(results[i].name + ":" + results[i].date);
       }`

all work, but when i delete `/* */` code have error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

Answer (score -1):

**getJSON()** will parse the JSON for you after fetching, so from then on, you are working with a simple Javascript array ([] marks an array in JSON).

You can get all the values in an array using a for loop:

```
   $.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
        for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });
```

**Another example:**

Parse a JSON string.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" )
;
```

Comment: `getJson` uses the GET method, asker wants to POST