# Update HTML content from JSON result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this HTML code:

```
<tr class="gris">
    <td width="6%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL}}"><img src="assets/play_icon.png" width="32" height="32" /></a></td>
    <td width="60%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL }}">{{ Here goes some title }}</a> <span></br>Descripción de la Pista o Podcast</span></td>
    <td width="17%" class="fecha">{{ Here goes some date}}</td>
    <td width="17%" class="tiempo">{{ Here goes some time}}</td>
</tr>
```

And I have a PHP code that returns a JSON like this:

```
{ "html_content" : [ { "description" : "Esta es una prueba de grabacion del podcast",
        "date" : "20130927",
        "hour" : "012100",
        "id" : "-317498614",
        "repro" : "0",
        "title" : "Prueba",
        "url" : "rtmp://46.4.158.7/kraa13/_definst_/kraa13/prueba1.flv"
      },
      { "description" : "260913",
        "date" : "20130926",
        "hour" : "192600",
        "id" : "-317498614",
        "repro" : "0",
        "title" : "260913",
        "url" : "rtmp://127.0.0.1/kraa13/_definst_/kraa13-317498614/260913.flv"
      }
    ],
  "response" : true
}
```

I should be able to generate as many `TR` as values are on JSON and of course replacing right values in generated `TR`. For example for each iteration where in sample code I have `{{ Here goes some URL }}` I should write the `url` value from JSON response.

**UPDATE**

I tried this code:

```
$(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://devserver/reader/podcast/podcast.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#podlist").html();
                if (data.response === false) {
                    $("#podlist").html(data.error);
                } else {
                    console.log(data.html_content);
                    if (data.html_content.length != 0) {
                        var htm = null;
                        for (var i in data.html_content) {
                            var jsonObj = data.html_content[i];
                            htm += "<tr class='gris'><td width='6%' class='titulo'><a href='" + jsonObj.url + "'><img src='assets/play_icon.png' width='32' height='32' /></a></td><td width='60%' class='titulo'><a href='" + jsonObj.url + "'>" + jsonObj.title + "</a> <span></br>" + jsonObj.description + "</span></td><td width='17%' class='fecha'>" + jsonObj.date + "</td><td width='17%' class='tiempo'>" + jsonObj.hour + "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        $("#podlist").append(htm);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                request.abort();
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: data.html_content is undefined
if (data.html_content.length != 0) {
```

Comment: Are you using AJAX which returns JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that you are talking about dynamically "Update HTML content from JSON result" using **AJAX**, I have come up with the following solution. Just write this code in your AJAX's *success* callback:

```
if(responseData.html_content.length != 0) {
  var htm = null;
  for(var i in responseData.html_content) {
      var jsonObj = responseData.html_content[i];
      htm += "<tr class='gris'><td width='6%' class='titulo'><a href='"+jsonObj.url+"'><img src='assets/play_icon.png' width='32' height='32' /></a></td><td width='60%' class='titulo'><a href='"+jsonObj.url+"'>"+jsonObj.title+"</a> <span></br>"+jsonObj.description+"</span></td><td width='17%' class='fecha'>"+jsonObj.date+"</td><td width='17%' class='tiempo'>"+jsonObj.hour+"</td></tr>";
  }
  $("#table-id").append(htm);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I'm using AJAX my bad not to mention before now I tried your code and I get `html_content` undefined and the json response is the same as main post, don't know where it fails

Comment: Ok, what _contentType_ and _dataType_ have you mentioned in _$.ajax_ method?

Comment: Don't worry I added `dataType: json` and now code works as I want, I just have a doubt: how I can maintain existent values and add just new ones? As you have it always add new entries each time it iterates so I change from `append` to `html` but what about if query returns 300 values and second time returns 600? I just want to add new 300 and leave existent 300, did you understand?

Comment: You will have to use _.append_ instead of _.html_ because _.html_ will **replace** the **existing** html elements with **new** elements ,whereas, _.append_ will retain the existing elements - as the name suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the table element, clear it's inner HTML, and then in $.each loop for Your response (it's a list) append desired rows. If "row"count is dynamic and You know it only after async request it's imo best approach.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
var myhtml = '<tr class="gris"><td width="6%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL}}"<img src="assets/play_icon.png" width="32" height="32" /></a></td><td width="60%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL }}">{{ Here goes some title }</a><span></br>Descripción de la Pista o Podcast</span></td><td width="17%" class="fecha">{{ Here goes some date}}</td><td width="17%" class="tiempo">{{ Here goes some time}}</td></tr>';
$.each(the_data,function(i , v) {
    $('.titulo a' , myhtml).attr('href' , v.url);
    // and so on
    $('.conatiner').append(myhtml);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to this format. You had to work on it a little bit. :)

```
$.post('test.php', { id: id },
  function (page) {
    $('.titulo a' , myhtml).attr('href' , page.html_content..url);
    $('.conatiner').append(page.html_content.data);
}, 'json');
```

Check the answer from here.. 
[How get parametrs from json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052705/how-get-parametrs-from-json#answer-19053138)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to maintain the template as

```
var template = '<tr class="gris">'+
    '<td width="6%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL}}"><img src="assets/play_icon.png" width="32" height="32" /></a></td>'+
    '<td width="60%" class="titulo"><a href="{{ Here goes some URL }}">{{ Here goes some title }}</a> <span></br>Descripción de la Pista o Podcast</span></td>'+
    '<td width="17%" class="fecha">{{ Here goes some date}}</td>'+
    '<td width="17%" class="tiempo">{{ Here goes some time}}</td>'+
'</tr>';

var jstring = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);

var htmlContent = jstring.html_content;
var i=0;
var t =template;
for(;i<htmlContent.length;i++){
    t = t.replace("{{ Here goes some URL}}", htmlContent[i].url);   
    //Similarly  do for the other values...
    jQuery("table").append(jQuery(t));
    t=template;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try doing

console.log(data);

Is the Ajax call returning data?

f12 and set a break point or use the "net" panel in your browser of choice to see what's coming back with your Ajax call.